# Django 3.0.5 runserver not working, no message after executing

Tags: django

I downloaded Django 3.0.5 on Windows, and when I went to start a new project and attempted to use runserver, I got nothing in the command prompt. No message. Just new prompt

```
C:\Users\\Desktop\wordcount>python3 manage.py runserver

C:\Users\\Desktop\wordcount>
```

Anyone know what's going one.

Comment: Hi Jcaber, this is very broad problem, make virtualenv and then work it will help you to understand better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
python manage.py runserver
```

And if that doesn't work install a virtual environment and install python 3 in it and then run the above command.